# Issue with 'google.cloud.storage'. module has no attribute 'Client'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

Trying to simply connect to the google-cloud-storage using these instructions;

https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/index.html

However, I keep getting the problem with the storage module, no client attribute.

```
from google.cloud import storage
# Instantiates a client
storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=creds, project='name')
# The name for the new bucket
bucket_name = 'my-new-bucket'
# Creates the new bucket
bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)
print('Bucket {} created.'.format(bucket.name))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem I've seen several times, and happens as well in other google.cloud modules. Most of the time it is related to a broken installation

Try to uninstall and then installgoogle.cloud packages. If no luck, try to use it on a newly created virtual environment (this will work for sure)

[Related git issue with same solution](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/3461)

Comment: I tried to uninstall and install again. Same issue. Also doing this locally.

Comment: can you try with a virtual environment? If you're using [conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) or without conda using [virtual env](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/). If you don't want to create a virtual environment and you're using anaconda, try to reinstall the whole anaconda

Comment: Created a new virtualenv, no success. :(

Comment: can you please share the exact pip command you're using for installing the cloud datastore package?

Comment: try `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage --user`

Comment: --user didn't work in virtualenv. Trying to do this on gcp shell.

Comment: wow, I'm out of solutions. In this case if I were you I would try to use the store client in a Google Colab (instant access to python 3 environment) in order to make sure I'm using the correct code. You can install packages in google colab by `!pip install google-cloud-storage`

Comment: After messing around for a bit, I managed to get it working. Created another new virtualenv, and installed google-cloud-storage normally.