# GCP Functions 'google.cloud.storage'. module has no attribute 'Client'

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am working with python 3.8 version in Google Cloud Functions and I need to store the file in the storage in the script I wrote. But I can't create storage client object.

This is my code:

```
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bucket_name')
blob = bucket.blob("dataframe.csv")
blob.upload_from_string(dataframe.to_csv(index=False))
```

some of this code and the error I get when I run it in functions with HTTP trigger:

```
storage_client = storage.Client() AttributeError: 'Storage' object has no attribute 'Client'
```

they are installed in the requirements.txt file

```
google-cloud-storage
google-api-python-client
google-auth-httplib2 
google-auth-oauthlib
oauth2client
argparse
pandas
opentelemetry-api
opentelemetry-instrumentation
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with 'google.cloud.storage'. module has no attribute 'Client'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55212535/issue-with-google-cloud-storage-module-has-no-attribute-client)

Comment: Thank you, I checked, but the answer to my question is not there, I applied what was said, but I can not solve this error.

Comment: Your error is not reproducible suggesting it's an issue with your environment. Please try creating a (new) virtualenv and install the minimal subset of libraries that you need `google-cloud-storage` and `pandas` and trying again.

Comment: Rereading your question, I note you say "GCP Functions" but don't reference Cloud Functions otherwise in your code. Perhaps add some clarification as to what you're trying to deploy (more code) and how?

Comment: Are you running this code in Google Cloud Functions? If so, I think you are including artifacts from your local installation with the deployment. Show how you are deploying this code.

Comment: I installed a new venv and the problem went away